# bokeh update high level chart with javascript callback

Tags: bokeh

I am using bokeh  to plot high level chart (Line) with a dataframe .
I have also widget to filter data showed by the graph.
I know how to do it with basic glyphs but not with high level charts.
Indeed basic plots are using ColumnDataSource as input and a javascript callback can take it as argument and trigger it. But for a dataframe as input, it does not seem possible.
I have the following error if I want to pass in args the dataframe df:

ValueError: expected an element of Dict(String, Instance(Model)), got {'df':   ......

Any idea?
Thanks.
David

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do that is by re-creating the entire plot each time and replacing it. See https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/Hn14aDN_5lk for example. I would stick with using a ColumnDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I have also to precise that I don't want to use a bokeh server but a standalone solution.
As a workaround I tried to replace the dataframe by a dataframe generated by a columndatasource like this :

plot=Line(source.data,x='x',y='y')
or 
plot=Line(source.to_df(),x='x',y='y')

with source=ColumnDataSource(df)

No more errors but nothing happens when triggering source in javascript callback.
Is it normal?
Thanks.
David

Comment: Read the link i attached in my answer. The method you are trying to use will simply not work. The only way for it to work is to replace the entire figure each time you change the data - which will achieve what you want visually, it will probably just be slower.

Comment: Thanks,I read the link but if I understand well, to recompute entirely the graph, I have to use bokeh's server, and can't do it with javascript. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
plot=Line(source.data,x='x',y='y') or plot=Line(source.to_df(),x='x',y='y')
```

then it is normal that your javascript callback doesn't trigger anything. Because you didn't pass any source to the line, you gave it the **dictionary** "data" from the source as defined in your python code at that time, and it will never change.

As said in the link of Okonomiyaki's answer, you should use bokeh.plotting if you want more interactions with js callbacks.

Comment: OK thanks. Understood. Plotting gives more interactions but the rendering is not what I am expecting. So I will do with server, Line and complete redraw on callback.